# How many Rads when wearing power armour

Tags: fallout-4

I maybe being stupid but I can't see how many rads I currently have, while wearing power armour?

I can take the armour off, and then it shows up as part of my health bar, but when in power armour it only seems to display the 'current' absorption of rads, not the total amount?

Am I missing it and it's on the UI somewhere?

Comment: Related: [What's the point of the radiation gauge when using power armor?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244113/108003)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's *very* subtle on the UI, but it's pretty much in the same place as it normally is. After you've soaked up some rads, look at your health gauge closely. You'll notice that some of it near the far-right end has a red bar, similar to the "red line" you'd see on a car's tachometer or many other analog displays.

It's extremely easy to miss, and I initially believed there was no rads display in Power Armor at all. But it is indeed there if you look close enough.

Another way to see rads while in Power Armor is by going into V.A.T.S.. There, you get a more typical HP bar, with the much-more-visible chunk of red at the end.

Comment: Only now you've pointed it out can I see it, that's really bad :/

Comment: Agreed. The way rads are shown in power armor is pretty bad and unhelpful...

Comment: Does the red bar actually show the rads? I felt like there was just a red section on the end, like at the end of a speedometer or tachometer.

Comment: Also, I think we determined you could see your normal health bar while scoped in or in VATS, which shows your rads.

Comment: @DCShannon I'm like 86% sure you're right about the scope, but I'd need to double-check again. And yes, that's actually rads. Have another look some time when you know you're clean and you'll see it's not there.

Comment: It is pretty easy to miss. I noticed it only after I reached at least level 20, when I started using power armour more.